# Creating a batch file to unzip multiple files, in php

Tags: php, batch-file

Here is my code which works:

```
<?php

$string = "e:
cd randomddirectory
unzip -o 84557".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted";

file_put_contents("extract.bat", $string);

?>
```

But when I try to account for multiple files to be unzipped like below, it fails:

```
<?php

$string = "e:
cd randomddirectory
unzip -o 84557".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted
unzip -o 84539".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted
unzip -o 84527".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted
unzip -o 84509".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted";

file_put_contents("extract.bat", $string);

?>
```

How do I modify the syntax to get the multiple unzips working? It's important the command is all within one string like above.

Comment: `But when I try to account for multiple files to be unzipped like below, it fails` - do you get an error message? What actually happens?

Comment: Also, if your zip files contain files with the same names, one of two things will happen: only the first file will be extracted and the subsequent calls will not ovewrite the existing files, or all will be extracted but only the last set of files will be there because they are overwritten every time

Comment: FYI there are flexible zip extensions available for php on windows

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `unzip` is a batch file on its own here. So put `call` before the `unzip` to make it work:

```
$string = "cd /d e:\\randomddirectory 
call unzip -o 84557".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted 
call unzip -o 84539".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted 
call unzip -o 84527".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted 
call unzip -o 84509".date("ymd")."*.zip -d Extracted";
```

I still think there are more sensible ways of doing this than creating a batch file and calling it from PHP. You'd run into probably every possible security barrier with this anyway.